# Date range on custom date field in SOQL Query

Tags: soql, query, error

Is there a limitation that prevent filtering SOQL queries on custom date fields?

This query works;

```
SELECT Id FROM SomeObject__c WHERE CreatedDate >= 2012-12-27T00:00:00Z
```

This one;

```
SELECT Id FROM SomeObject__c WHERE CustomDate__c >= 2012-12-27T00:00:00Z
```

Returns the error

> value of filter criterion for field 'CustomDate__c ' must be of
>   type date and should not be enclosed in quotes.

...I've double check that `CustomDate__c` is a date field.

Comment: Is it "Date" or "Date/time"  the query needs to be written specific to the data type.

Comment: It is a [Date] field

Comment: you are comparing date field to  datetime. Remove the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id FROM SomeObject__c WHERE CustomDate__c >= 2012-12-27
```

and see if it works.  If so, the Custom_Date__c field is Date, not Date/Time, and requires a different where statement to resolve.

Comment: THanks HomerJ, that works and feeling rather silly now.  Will accept and leave question in case someone else gets hung up on the same thing.